# TableArrayController.arrangedObjects in Swift 3 Type 'Any' has no subscript members error

Tags: swift3, nsarraycontroller, macos-sierra

I just upgraded to Swift 3 and I have the following issue. Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func closeSupportsModal(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let selectedRow = supportsTable.selectedRow
    supportTableArrayController.arrangedObjects[selectedRow].setValue(vertRestPopUp.titleOfSelectedItem!, forKey: "vertic")   
    supportTableArrayController.arrangedObjects[selectedRow].setValue(rotatRestPopUp.titleOfSelectedItem!, forKey: "horiz")
    mainWindow.endSheet((sender as! NSButton).window!)

    var suppArray = [[Int]]()
    var row1 = [Int]()
    var row2 = [Int]()

    for i in 0..<supports.count {
        let vert = supportTableArrayController.arrangedObjects[i].value(forKey: "vertic")!
        let rot = supportTableArrayController.arrangedObjects[i].value(forKey: "horiz")!
        var vertS = 0
        var rotS = 0

        if vert as! String == "Free" {
            vertS = 0
        }else{
            vertS = 1
        }
        if rot as! String == "Free" {
            rotS = 0
        }else{
            rotS = 1
        }


        row1.append(vertS)
        row2.append(rotS)
    }

    suppArray.append(row1)
    suppArray.append(row2)

    for j in 0..<suppArray.count {
        for k in 0..<suppArray[j].count {
            print(suppArray[j][k])
        }
    }
}
```

For any row with `supportTableArrayController.arrangedObjects` I have the error:

> "Type 'Any' has no subscript members error".

Any suggestions how to resolve this?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
(supportTableArrayController.arrangedObjects as AnyObject).object(at: i) // and so forth...
```

Seems to work for me. Need to cast the arrangedObjects to AnyObject instead of just Any